# How to use runnable jar in another class?

Tags: java

I have a runnable java jar file that I need somehow to run (pass params, fetch output) from another java class I'm working on. How do I do that? Do I import it as a package somehow, call it on runtime? Can I invoke "main" method from it or do I just run it with "exec"? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add it to your `CLASSPATH` and call either the `main()` method or any other public method which it provides (and which is documented). There is no difference between "normal" and "runnable" jar files, besides an entry in the manifest.

One subtle detail you might need to consider is that runnable jar files are usually self-contained - that is, they contain all required classes, including classes from third party libraries. If you are using the same third party libraries in your project, make sure that there are no conflicts, e.g. by removing the separate third party jar files from your project.

See [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for more information.

Comment: So I should add it as a library in Java Build Path and then import it?

Comment: Yes - in Eclipse, add it to the build path as you do with other jar files, and then import the necessary packages in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Import it in your code if you need something, that you can not achieve from command line `exec` solution. Note, you can get problems, if you trying to use some methods from jar file itself, and author changes it later.

Consider [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) pattern, to put some abstraction layer between jar file and your code, If you not sure, that you use public API.

If jar file is library with stable API, you can be more confident, while using it in your project.

Besides, importing jar file and use methods from it is faster, than parsing process output.

Comment: I have a source of the jar file and it will not be changed. So just to be clear: I use "import com.something.something;" to import the jar and then I somehow call the main method from it?

Comment: @Caballero Yes. `main`, or, if you want, another, more specific method.

Answer (score 0):

u can import it to your project and then call the publicly exposed methods in that jar from within your application.